# await is causing my update in findOneAndUpdate to run twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am setting a variable based on a function using findOneAndUpdate() and need everything else to wait until the variable is set. However, when I do this the update runs twice because I use "await" before it.

```
documentUpdate = { $set: { price: price }, $push: { ips: ipa }, $inc: { likes: 1 }};
returnObject = await getStockWithTrue(stockName, documentUpdate, price);
```

I later try to return the object and only works if I use await. If i take await away then the function works properly (only updates once) and sends to mongoDB, but then the variable returnObject is not able to be used.

For example, if I use await the return Object will push an ip address twice and increase the likes by 2.
Then. If i take await away the returnObject is not the correct model that is returned by getStockWithTrue() because everything is executing before it is complete.

here is the getStockWithTrue function using the findOneAndUpdate()

```
 const getStockWithTrue = (stockName, updateDocument, price) => {
    return Stock.findOneAndUpdate(
      { stock: stockName },
      updateDocument,
      { new: true, upsert: true },
      (error, stock) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error);
        // If stock is not already in database
        if (!error && !stock) {
          stock = new Stock({
            stock: stockName,
            price: price,
            likes: 1,
            ips: ipa,
          });
        }
        stock.save((error, result) => {
          if (error) return console.log(error);
          else return result;
        });
      }
    );
  };
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution to solving this, but I have been going at it for days now as the answer is eluding me. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: The [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) warns about this. The update callback updates the record and then the `await` forces the equivalent of _resolve_ and that updates it again. It's never a good idea to mix callbacks and async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating your code. When you are using `upsert: true` then you don't need to manually check for the stock and create (if it does not exist). The [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#std-term-upsert) option will create a document if it does not exist.

The simplified version of your code could be:

```
documentUpdate = { $set: { price: price }, $push: { ips: ipa }, $inc: { likes: 1 }};
returnObject = await getStockWithTrue(stockName, documentUpdate, price);
```

Then later

```
const getStockWithTrue = async (stockName, documentUpdate) => {
  return await Stock.findOneAndUpdate(
    { stock: stockName },
    documentUpdate,
    {
       upsert: true,
       new: true
    }
  )
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: wow. You made that a lot easier... Thank you! that worked splendidly.